# value "strike" always equals one

Tags: c#, android

In my c# game for android the if statements check if the player has swiped left and the closest object is a certain object(Left Right Up or Down) then the strike value will equal one but they are not working as expected.For some reason whenever I start the game the strike value always = 1 and it should be set to 0.
Another small side problem is that the wait Coroutines stop working for 2 seconds after you have swiped a few times.

All help is much apreciated

Here is the c# script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwipeChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxTime;
    public float minSwipeDistance;

    float startTime;
    float endTime;

    Vector3 startPos;
    Vector3 endPos;

    float swipeDistance;
    float swipeTime;
    public float swipeScore;

    public GameObject left;
    public GameObject right;
    public GameObject up;
    public GameObject down;
    public GameObject swipeChecker;
    public GameObject[] platforms = new GameObject[5];

    public bool leftSwipe;
    public bool rightSwipe;
    public bool upSwipe;
    public bool downSwipe;

    public float strike;

    public GameObject closestPlatform;

    // Use this for initialization

    public GameObject FindClosestPlatform()
    {
        GameObject[] gos;

        gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("platform");

        GameObject closest = null;
        float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject go in gos)

        {
            Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
            float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
            if (curDistance < distance)
            {
                closest = go;
                distance = curDistance;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }


    public IEnumerator leftwait()
    {
        leftSwipe = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        leftSwipe = false;
    }

    public IEnumerator rightwait()
    {
        rightSwipe = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        rightSwipe = false;
    }
    public IEnumerator upwait()
    {
        upSwipe = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        upSwipe = false;
    }
    public IEnumerator downwait()
    {
        downSwipe = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        downSwipe = false;
    }
    public IEnumerator pause()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    }


    void Start()
    {
        strike = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {



        closestPlatform = FindClosestPlatform();
        left = GameObject.Find("PurpleTile(Clone)");
        right = GameObject.Find("OrangeTile(Clone)");
        up = GameObject.Find("BlueTile(Clone)");
        down = GameObject.Find("RedTile(Clone)");


        if ((closestPlatform == left) && !leftSwipe) 
        { 
            strike = 1;

        }
        if ((closestPlatform == right) && !rightSwipe)
        {
            strike = 1;

        }
        if ((closestPlatform == up) && !upSwipe)
        {
            strike = 1;

        }
        if ((closestPlatform == down) && !downSwipe)
        {
            strike = 1;

        }




        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                startTime = Time.time;
                startPos = touch.position;
            }
            else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                endTime = Time.time;
                endPos = touch.position;

                swipeDistance = (endPos - startPos).magnitude;
                swipeTime = endTime - startTime;

                if (swipeTime < maxTime && swipeDistance > minSwipeDistance)
                {
                    swipe();
                }
            }

        }

    }    


    void swipe()
    {
        Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;
        if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) > Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
        {
            Debug.Log("Horizontal Swipe");
            if (distance.x > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Right Swipe");
                rightSwipe = true;
                StartCoroutine(rightwait());
            }
            if (distance.x < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Left Swipe");
                StartCoroutine(leftwait());              
            }

        }

        else if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) < Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
        {
            Debug.Log("Vertical Swipe");
            if (distance.y > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Up Swipe");
                StartCoroutine(upwait());
            }
            if (distance.y < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Down Swipe");
                StartCoroutine(downwait());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so apparently, one of the if conditions are being met in the block of code. debug.log(strike) right before the if and after the `if` block of code you're using to determine if it's set to 1. Are you forgetting to revert back to 0 if nothing is happening because you're only doing it at program start. Once it becomes 1 I see nowhere where you set it back to 0. If that's the case, you could probably just move that strike=0; line down into the start of your update. But I'm only guessing what you're doing with this.

Comment: I changed each one so that it will set strike to 1 then wait for half a second and then set it back to 0.Now when I start the game strike always = 0 even if I dont swipe at all heres what each one looks like now  if ((closestPlatform == left) && !leftSwipe) { strike = 1;
            StartCoroutine(pause());
            strike = 0;

Comment: It seems putting it in the update loop fixed it.Thanks for your help.